# Node.js with knex + Mysql migrate error while rename column cause default value

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new in `nodejs` and my english is bad please help me, I am just trying to migrate my database in `nodejs(express)` using `knex`, and I'm using Mysql for database. I want to rename one field in table, and when I try to migrate my database, I got some problem that say error default value.

here is what I'm trying to do :

My migrate

```js
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.table ('tbl_skills', function(table) {
        table.renameColumn('preminum_price', 'premium_price')
    })
};
```

Here my database structure

```
 Name           | Datatype | length | Default             |
    id             | INT      | 20     | No default          |
    preminum_price | DOUBLE   | 5,2    | No default          |
    insertdate     | TIMESTAMP|        | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
    updatedate     | TIMESTAMP|        | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
```

and this what I got when I'm trying knex migrate:latest

```
migration file "20191125105226_alter_tbl_skills.js" failed
migration failed with error: alter table `tbl_skills` change `preminum_price` `premium_price` double(5,2) NOT NULL - ER_INVALID_DEFAULT: Invalid default value for 'insertdate'
Error: ER_INVALID_DEFAULT: Invalid default value for 'insertdate'
```

I dont know to how set value for insertdate with default value. Please help

Answer (score 2):

That is most probably because of server SQL Mode - [NO_ZERO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date).

In strict mode, don't allow '0000-00-00' as a valid date. You can still insert zero dates with the IGNORE option. When not in strict mode, the date is accepted but a warning is generated. If you have access to my.ini (mysql conf file) remove the NO_ZERO_DATA from sql-mode and restart the server.

You can check it with SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'