# knex migration - 'ER_INVALID_DEFAULT: Invalid default value for 'timestamp'

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, knex.js

I have a knex chema migration to create a table, with the line -

```
exports.up = async function(knex) {
return knex.schema.createTable("newTable", table => {
table.timestamp("timestamp").notNullable();
})
}
```

I am getting an error `ER_INVALID_DEFAULT: Invalid default value for 'timestamp'`

I've tried to give a default of null and remove the notNullable() or a default of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but nothing seems to work (maybe I have a wrong syntax?)

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to my.ini (mysql conf file) remove the NO_ZERO_DATE from sql-mode and restart the server.

You can check it with SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'

For the complete answer, follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59028179/12925521)

Comment: Complete answer should be in the answer. Consider improving the quality of your answer.